# Third asp.net button doesn't open a jQuery dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a very basic testing asp.net web application. There is one `<asp:Button>` that pops a jQuery dialog. In this dialog there is another `<asp:Button>` that makes a `<div>` tag visible, and in this `<div>` tag there is a third `<asp:Button>`. So far everything is okay.
Now according to my code the third button should pop a second jQuery dialog, but this never happens. Where am I mistaking?

Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="btn" />
    <div id="div1">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="btn1" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div2" runat="server" visible="false">
                                <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="btn2" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    <div id="div3" style="display:none">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
```

And here is the code for the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var dialogOpts = {
            resizable: false,
            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: "710px"
        };

        $('#div3').dialog(dialogOpts).parent().appendTo($("#form1"));;
        $(function () {
            $("#div3").dialog({
                maxWidth: 1050,
                maxHeight: 534,
                width: 1050,
                height: 534,
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#btn2").click(function () {
                $("#div3").dialog("open");
                return false
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dialogOpts = {
            resizable: false,
            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: "710px"
        };

        $('#div1').dialog(dialogOpts).parent().appendTo($("#form1"));;
        $(function () {
            $("#div1").dialog({
                maxWidth: 1050,
                maxHeight: 534,
                width: 1050,
                height: 534,
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#btn").click(function () {
                $("#div1").dialog("open");
                return false
            });
        });
    </script>
```

It is placed in the body and so far only the first jQuery pops up.
And  this is my c# function that makes the second `<div>` tag visible:

```
 protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        div2.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`visible = false`

essentially prevents element from rendering. If you register the onclick event for the unrendered (UNRENDERED, not display:none nor visibility:hidden, your button does not physically reside in the page), the onclick event does not register to anything at all. After you show your button in the update panel, there is nothing to be run on click, because no click handling has been set (the button did not exist in the time of

```
$("#btn2").click(function () {
            $("#div3").dialog("open");
            return false
        });
```

)

Comment: okay, i see. removing the `visible = false` seems to fix the problem with opening the second jQuery dialog. But how else can I make the second div to shows up only on `btn2` click?

Comment: you can for example set css property display to none. Another approach would be to convert the adding of click handling to a function, which in turn you would assign to the OnClientClick.

Comment: can you help me with some code? setting `style="display:none"` didn't work.